# Programmatically switch between WinForm and Console

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, console-application

I am learning C#, and I have 1 project called "Examples". In this project I have some WinForms, and I know how to call one WinForm or another when my program starts (I just change the Application.Run parameter to reflect the Form I want to load).

What I want to know is can I programmatically start a console application somehow? So ... I have this Program class that Visual Studio made when I created the project (it was a WinForm the first time I created it) that looks like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new ______ ); //I left ______ because I change the name to the form I want
}
```

So what I want to do is comment that out and do this:

```
static void Main()
{
    new ConsoleApplication();
}
```

and have that run a console application. Right now it runs through the class I have called ConsoleApplication, but it doesn't actually run as a Console App. By that I mean, right now ConsoleApplication looks like this:

```
class ConsoleApplication
{
    public ConsoleApplication()
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

but the console never appears. Do I need to create console applications in a different project? I was hoping to have one project with all my examples (Console and WinForms) and just tell the program which one to launch by changing the Main method. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Set project type in properties to "Console Application" instead of "Windows Application"

Comment: @m.rogalski Thanks! That's what I needed! Now it works how I want it to :)

Answer (score 2):

try this. Add it to your WinForm.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AllocConsole();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a console application, and reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll`. Then you can create a form and go like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestCWF
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var mf = new MainForm();
      mf.ShowDialog();

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

I've just seen you've got a forms-app and want to open a console. In this case Stan's answer may fit better.